# How to change marker color in Kendo UI Map?

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

i got the following problem:

I use the Kendo UI Map.

How can I change the color of the markers via remote data)

In my exmaple I got something like this:

```
data =[{"name": "test1", "shape":"pinTarget", "latlng":[30.268107, -97.744821]},
       {"name": "test2","shape":"mystyle", "latlng":[40.268107, -97.744821]}];


$("#map").kendoMap({
    center : [ 30.268107, -97.744821 ],
    zoom : 3,

    layers : [ {
         type : "tile",
         urlTemplate : "http://#= subdomain #.tile2.opencyclemap.org/transport/#= zoom     #/#= x #/#= y #.png",
         subdomains : [ "a", "b", "c" ],
         attribution : "&copy; <a href='http://osm.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap contributors</a>." + "Tiles courtesy of <a href='http://www.opencyclemap.org/'>Andy Allan</a>"
    } ,{
         type: "marker",
         dataSource: data,

         locationField: "latlng",
         titleField: "name"}],
});
```

And in the css something like this:

```
 .k-marker-my-style {
    background-image: url("styles/Bootstrap/markers.png");
    border: solid 1px #00f;

  }
```

I know that the markers are pictures. How can I change these pictures addicted to the shape field in the dataSource.

In example when the shapefield is "shape":red" the marker should be use like picture1.png and if the shapefiled is "shape": "green" the marker should be like picture2.png.

Does anyone have an idea?

Greets

Comment: might be helpful for you. http://www.telerik.com/forums/marker-colour

Comment: Yes I have seen that. I have got it right with the frame, but only local not with datasource :-(

Comment: Do you know how to change color but, not using marker, using geojson layer?